# Exporting Selenium code to a file people without selenium can use

Tags: selenium, export

Is there a way to export Selenium code into some sort of file I could send to others to use without selenium? Preferably inserting it into some html file or something they wouldn't have to install on their computers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of, depending on what you use currently.

If you use the IDE, then yes. The steps the IDE records are essentially put into a HTML file that it reads. You can just give that HTML file to someone else, have them import it into the IDE and it would pick up from there. This has the dependency that the user **must** have an FF version supported by the IDE.

If you use the WebDriver, then no. At least not without much work - even just due to the dependencies. For instance, you have the various drivers, that the user would need to have a copy of for the tests to work. You have the language that the tests were coded in, for instance Java - you'd have to ensure the user has Java.

You could package them up into a nice installer - whereby the installer gets the dependencies for the user, but this will be slow, unreliable and totally not worth the time and effort you place into it. Think of it when you are installing large programs - it's also downloading lots of dependencies for that application too. Visual Studio/Eclipse are prime examples, they depend on hundreds of things. So when you install them, they are not just installing the core files, but the things they depend on too. You could replicate the same thing.

Comment: So there is nothing I could to do export it to something where my clients wouldn't have to install anything correct?

Comment: Afraid not, your best bet is the IDE option.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Export your Test Case Or Test Suite in different languages.

If you are using **Selenium IDE** follow these steps:

1. After recording your Test Case click on file menu.
2. Click on Export Test Suite As.
   [image]
3. Save this file.
4. Now you can send this file.

Comment: If you got your answer do not forget to accept it, for accept you have to just click on right symbol under my answer.

Comment: I tried that already, and it is just opening as a webpage. I was trying to send a script. I should have been a little more descriptive I'm sorry.

Comment: in this case in which language you want to send you script?

Comment: Any that would be self sufficient such as a bat file or an exe.

Comment: None of those are working to change into a .bat or anything though. Sorry I'm such a pain, but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: I'm sorry, how can I convert it? Every time I do, I lose most of the commands

Comment: that's okay. Appreciate the help anyways.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it hasn't answered my question yet.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a Selenium test you would need one this too things:

- Selenium IDE running on Firefox, in this case you just export as html and import in the other computer
- The runtime of the specific language you are using to export (i.e. for jre, .net for C# etc.) plus the selenium-server running

As for your question, I would say there is no way to export a test case into a single file to be executable by itself.